# How do we share full NetLogo models here when working on a problem?

Tags: netlogo

I'm pretty new on this list, and trying to answer a question posted here on StackOverflow and i am wondering if there is some standard way to post entire models here, not just the "CODE" tab portion. Or for that matter even an image of the view screen.

I don't see any place to put attachments on posts or answers.  I suppose I could upload the model to the NetLogo-users Google users-group, which does have a place to upload files, and cross-reference it here.  I suppose I could try to open an email channel to the user and send them email with an attachment.  I suppose I could post it on GitHub.

But is there some way to attach a full .nlogo file right here that I'm missing? Some interfaces are really complicated and only looking at the CODE tab is not adequate.

And, yes since the .nlogo model is pure text I could paste the entire thing into a window here ( which would object to having code in a text window of course) but that's a lot of extra characters in the post.

Comment: for anyone interested, here's a link to netlogo-users: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/netlogo-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not. This is actually more of a problem for the questioning than answering as it can be difficult to get the person asking the question to post the relevant bit of code, including the other bits of code that lead up to the problem and give key information like what the contents of a variable may be. NetLogo does not lend itself to MWE at all, and beginners simply don't have the experience to replace interface variables with global variables etc.

Uploading to Google users group and cross referencing is likely to get the question/answer closed as it's not complete. But StackOverflow has a different purpose than the users group - it is supposed to be focussed on specific questions with specific answers - such things as syntax problems and bugs, not design. The last thing we want is interfaces or full models. We tend to be more lenient than other areas of StackOverflow because we know NetLogo has a very high proportion of beginners without support and that MWE in NetLogo doesn't really make sense, but questions that require full models are definitely out of scope.

Comment: Thanks Jen!  I appreciate any orienting I can get!

Comment: I agree with Jen's point of view. Stack Overflow isn't one-stop shopping for any possible question about NetLogo or request for help with NetLogo. And that's actually a good thing; it makes SO better at serving the purposes it *does* serve.